# C++ 2D Vector setting a position within the vector

Tags: c++, class, robotics, 2d-vector

I have an assignment to make a robot controller for a University project. At the moment it is going quite well, but I have a niggling bug that is just darn annoying and I can't seem to correct it.

Basically, I have to design a contrasting controller to enable random movement while avoiding obstacles. So, I have a robot which appears as "R" on the console, which is within a 10 by 10 area. Here is the code I use to initialise my 2D vector, and then draw the grid:

```
void matrix::init() // init my 2D vector
{
    dot = 10; // 10 by 10 area
    vector2D.resize(dot); 
    for (int i=0; i<dot; i++)
    {
        vector2D[i].resize(dot); 
    }
}

void matrix::draw() // drawing the vector to the screen
{
    for(int i=0; i<dot; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<dot; j++)
        {
            cout <<vector2D[i][j]<<"."; // I being the Y access, J the X access
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void matrix::update() 
{
    init();
    draw();     
}
```

This is in its own class called `matrix.cpp`, which is then called in the main.cpp with `m.update();` `m` being an object of `matrix`

Now, the robot position on screen is being set with this code within the `matrix.cpp` class

```
void matrix::robotPosition(int x, int y)
{
    bot = 'R';
    cout << "X Pos"<< x <<endl;
    cout << "Y Pos"<< y <<endl;
    vector2D[x][y] = bot; // Outputting location of robot onto the grid / matrix
}
```

There is more code I have developed to control the position on screen, but I don't think that is needed at this point in my question.

```
int main()
{
    matrix m;
    robot r;

    while(true)
    {
        m.update(); // vector2D init and draw
        m.robotPosition(r.getX(), r.getY());
        r.update();
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Every time my program loops through the while loop it draws another robot on the screen, but doesn't seem to remove the old one. The code works by assigning a certain `X` and `Y` in the 2D vector with the `char 'R'` (Which is my Robot). Is my thinking correct that I will have to draw the 2D matrix after each movement cycle?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first set the robot position to, say, (5,5), you will set `vector2D[5][5]` to `R`. Then if you set the position to something like (5,6), you will set `vector2D[5][6]` to `R`. Now both elements `[5][5]` and `[5][6]` are set to `R`, so the robot is in both positions.

There are a few solutions that depend on how you want to design it:

1. You can store the current robot position in `matrix` and at the beginning of `robotPosition` set that position to whatever the non-robot character is. This will clear the previous position before setting the new one.
2. You can clear the entire matrix at the beginning of each frame. You *are* calling `update` at the beginning of each frame, which attempts to resize the vectors to exactly the same size they already are - this doesn't clear it. Instead, you should do that work in the constructor, and you can turn `init` into a `clear` function.
3. If you want to use a different `matrix` for each time step, then you need to move the declaration of `matrix m;` into the `while` loop. Then you have one for each frame which should be cleared during construction (if you move the `init` stuff to the constructor).

Comment: Yeah I was on the correct line of thought. Thank you for those three different ways of fixing my issue. At the moment I've done a quick fix by making a new matrix on each time step, but I do feel like this is a bad way of doing it. I quite like the second way of doing it though, so I shall work on that! Thank you